# IntelliJ Plugin for PhpStorm: "WorkspaceFileIndex is not initialized yet" error during plugin execution

Tags: java, intellij-idea, console, intellij-plugin

I'm developing an IntelliJ plugin for PhpStorm, and I'm encountering an error during the execution of my plugin. It occurs every time I run my plugin. Could someone help to resolve it?

The error message I'm getting is:

```
configuration must be postponed until the project is fully loaded.
    at com.intellij.op2023-11-06 20:51:14,855 [   5485] SEVERE - #c.i.w.c.f.i.WorkspaceFileIndexImpl - WorkspaceFileIndex is not initialized yet, empty data is returned. Activities which use the project configuration must be postponed until the project is fully loaded.
java.lang.Throwable: WorkspaceFileIndex is not initialized yet, empty data is returned. Activities which use the project enapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:370)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.core.fileIndex.impl.WorkspaceFileIndexImpl.getMainIndexData(WorkspaceFileIndexImpl.kt:281)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.core.fileIndex.impl.WorkspaceFileIndexImpl.getOrCreateIndexData(WorkspaceFileIndexImpl.kt:273)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.core.fileIndex.impl.WorkspaceFileIndexImpl.getFileInfo(WorkspaceFileIndexImpl.kt:240)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.core.fileIndex.impl.WorkspaceFileIndexImpl.findFileSet(WorkspaceFileIndexImpl.kt:200)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.core.fileIndex.impl.WorkspaceFileIndexImpl.isInContent(WorkspaceFileIndexImpl.kt:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectFileIndexImpl.isInContent(ProjectFileIndexImpl.java:206)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$1MatchSink.accept(MatchOps.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.tryAdvance(AbstractList.java:706)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:632)
    at one.util.streamex.AbstractStreamEx.anyMatch(AbstractStreamEx.java:543)
    at com.jetbrains.php.robo.run.RoboTasksToolWindowUpdateService$RoboBulkFileListener.after(RoboTasksToolWindowUpdateService.java:74)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.invokeMethod(MessageBusImpl.kt:699)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.invokeListener(MessageBusImpl.kt:663)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImplKt.executeOrAddToQueue(MessageBusImpl.kt:491)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.ToDirectChildrenMessagePublisher.publish$intellij_platform_core(CompositeMessageBus.kt:310)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessagePublisher.invoke(MessageBusImpl.kt:448)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy51.after(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.lambda$fireAfterEvents$19(PersistentFSImpl.java:1326)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.runSuppressing(PersistentFSImpl.java:955)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.fireAfterEvents(PersistentFSImpl.java:1323)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.applyMultipleEvents(PersistentFSImpl.java:1300)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.processEventsImpl(PersistentFSImpl.java:1263)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.AsyncEventSupport.processEventsFromRefresh(AsyncEventSupport.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.fireEventsInWriteAction(RefreshSessionImpl.java:233)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.lambda$fireEvents$1(RefreshSessionImpl.java:214)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$runEdtProgressWriteAction$7(ApplicationImpl.java:972)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:186)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$13(CoreProgressManager.java:604)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:679)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:603)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:173)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.PotemkinProgress.runInSwingThread(PotemkinProgress.java:150)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$runEdtProgressWriteAction$8(ApplicationImpl.java:972)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteActionWithClass(ApplicationImpl.java:980)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runEdtProgressWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:970)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteActionWithNonCancellableProgressInDispatchThread(ApplicationImpl.java:953)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.lambda$fireEvents$2(RefreshSessionImpl.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteAction.lambda$run$1(WriteAction.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteActionWithClass(ApplicationImpl.java:980)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1006)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.WriteAction.run(WriteAction.java:86)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshSessionImpl.fireEvents(RefreshSessionImpl.java:208)
    at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.RefreshQueueImpl.lambda$queueSession$2(RefreshQueueImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl$Submission.lambda$safeTransferToEdt$7(NonBlockingReadActionImpl.java:711)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:208)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:190)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:861)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$4.run(ApplicationImpl.java:478)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:41)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:318)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:792)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:739)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:761)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:685)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent$lambda$10(IdeEventQueue.kt:589)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWithoutImplicitRead(ApplicationImpl.java:1485)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:589)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.access$_dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:67)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:369)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1$1.compute(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:368)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue$dispatchEvent$processEventRunnable$1$1.invoke(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity$lambda$1(IdeEventQueue.kt:992)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueueKt.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.kt:992)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent$lambda$7(IdeEventQueue.kt:363)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:861)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.kt:405)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:207)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:92)
```

gradle.build.kts

```
plugins {
  id("java")
  id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.0"
  id("org.jetbrains.intellij") version "1.15.0"
}

group = "MagicPoint"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

// Configure Gradle IntelliJ Plugin
// Read more: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/tools-gradle-intellij-plugin.html
intellij {
  version.set("2023.2.2")
  type.set("PS") // Target IDE Platform

  plugins.set(listOf("com.jetbrains.php:232.9921.55"))
}

tasks {
  // Set the JVM compatibility versions
  withType<JavaCompile> {
    sourceCompatibility = "17"
    targetCompatibility = "17"
  }
  withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
  }

  patchPluginXml {
    sinceBuild.set("222")
    untilBuild.set("232.*")
  }

  signPlugin {
    certificateChain.set(System.getenv("CERTIFICATE_CHAIN"))
    privateKey.set(System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY"))
    password.set(System.getenv("PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD"))
  }

  publishPlugin {
    token.set(System.getenv("PUBLISH_TOKEN"))
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation("org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.32")
}
```

plugin.xml

```
<idea-plugin>
  <id>Magic point</id>

  <name>Magic point</name>

  <vendor email="" url="">Magic point</vendor>

  <depends>com.jetbrains.php</depends>
  <depends>com.intellij.modules.platform</depends>

  <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <codeInsight.lineMarkerProvider language="PHP" implementationClass="MagicLineMarker" />
  </extensions>

  <actions>
    <group id="startPoint" text="Test" popup="true">
      <add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="last"/>
      <action class="controllers.ViewController" text="Create View">
      </action>
    </group>
  </actions>
</idea-plugin>
```

I have read the intellij open api sdk.
I setup a new project but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Please see https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-help.html for the best resources to get help with the plug-in development for IntelliJ IDEA platform.